# Making Sqoop1 work with Hadoop2

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2, sqoop2

I have had a hard time making sqoop1 work on hadoop2. I always run int `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool` error which suggests that sqoop1 is trying to use hadoop1. But i had downloaded the sqoop1 jar with hadoop 2.0.4-alpha release from http://www.us.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.5/.

Then why does it not work with hadoop2?

PS: I have tried hard to make sqoop2 work, but i faced lot of problems in the setup.

Also, this post http://mmicky.blog.163.com/blog/static/1502901542013118115417262/ suggests that it should work, but i keep running into this ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Whatever classpath i was setting was probably being overridden by the hadoop executable. So i had to modify the hadoop executable at the place where it called the java command and add a -cp flag with the classpath of my hadoop jars like below:

exec "$JAVA" -cp "$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.4.1/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*" $JAVA_HEAP_MAX $HADOOP_OPTS $CLASS "$@"